# Python: Assign variables from array

Tags: python, list, iterable-unpacking

I have some code in Python:

```
repost_pid = row[0]
repost_permalink = row[1]
repost_domain = row[2]
repost_title = row[3]
repost_submitter = row[4]
```

Is there a one-liner way to assign these variables?

Also, what would I do if I wanted to skip a value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can separate each variable with a `,` to perform [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
repost_pid, repost_permalink, repost_domain, repost_title, repost_submitter = row
```

If there is a particular value that you are not concerned about, [the convention is to assign it to an underscore variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python), e.g.

```
repost_pid, repost_permalink, _, repost_title, repost_submitter = row
```

Comment: Great! Suppose I want to skip a value (i.e. I dont want row[2]), what would I put for its value?

Comment: Note that this assumes there are no further entries in `row`.

Comment: @Bijan you need to mention that in your question.

Comment: @Bijan a `_`, by convention: `foo, _, bar = [1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @Bijan: Anything but `_`.  While some people use that as a convention, it's not a good idea.

Comment: (And the reason it is not a good idea is because it is common to do `from gettext import gettext as _` when doing i18n. Using it as a dummy variable would break translations)

Comment: @spectras: A more important reason not to use it is that it is pretty opaque.  Almost everyone who encounters this for the first time mistakes it as some special syntax (as it is in e.g. Haskell), which it isn't.  It's just a somewhat weird variable name.  Using `unused_doamin` or whatever documents much better what's going on, won't confuse anyone, won't conflict with the gettext alias and is supported by all common linters, so they won't warn about the unused variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip a value in sequence unpacking, you can do:

```
>>> row
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> r0,r1,r3=row[0:2]+[row[3]]
>>> r0,r1,r3
(0, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
repost_pid,repost_permalink, repost_domain, repost_title, repost_submitter = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]
```

but it won't be readable